# check (with a function) if a String input from user is a character or integer. (java)

Tags: java, string, input, char, int

I've looked around a lot, but i'm still very new to java and everything i've found that relates to String input and char/number is just lost to me. I've seen various different ways to check if it is a number or char but i'm not sure which one to use in my case. The goal in my program is to have a user input a number, then check&print if that number is even or odd. But don't restrict the user to inputting only an integer. I thought to make the input a 'char' but I can't get scanner to accept it, it wants to convert it to a string. so now I'm using a string input but i am not sure how to write a function below the main that i can call to check if the user's input was a number or character. I don't want the whole program written for me, just how to solve this one issue. I'll come back for more assistance if i can't get further :)
Also, it helps a hell of a lot if you can explain what each part of the code is doing when you respond to help me understand which commands do what exactly. Thanks in advance for any response!

Ok i'll post my code, i know it is all kinds of broken but i really have no idea where to go next.  I want the user to input whatever he wants, a char , symbol like & $ #, or a number. But i want the program to give him an error if he inputs anything besides a number. So i figure I have to have them input a String but i dont know how to use my test functions with scanner inputting a string. Ugh, i'm so lost. I need it to check the string to see if it is a character or a number, and if it is a character, throw them an error. if it is a number, check to see if it is even or odd then respond which one it is.

public class firsttry2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter a character or number. Seriously, though, it is meant to be a number, but you can put whatever you want here. If it isn't a number however, you will get an error message.");


    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);


    String input=in.next();
    boolean x=checkevenodd(input);

    //no idea where to go from here and what i have so far is probably badly broken
    //i cant get checkevenodd to work with my scanner input because it's expecting an integer but it's getting a string.









}
public static boolean checkevenodd(int input1){
    if (input1%2==0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

public static boolean checkchartype() {

}
}

Comment: If you know that your may input either numeric value or string use nextLine() method in the scanner. Then you will get a String.
then you can check whether it is numerical or character

Answer (score 4):

Just pass the user input to `Integer.parseInt(String)`, if it throws `NumberFormatException`, its not `Integer`. Further check the length of string, if it's 1, it has to be a character. But in your case, no need to check for character, just restrict for Integer. If exception comes, prompt for wrong input.

```
int i = 0;

try
{
    i = Integer.parseInt(readit.next());
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: What about large numbers? This is an integer: 123456789123456789, but it would be interpreted as not an "integer" by your code because it's not in the `int` range, but it's still an "integer"

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) (or [`Long.parseLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29)), you'll still be restricted to number in the range of a 32-bit (or 64-bit) signed integer. But you don't need to *parse* a java primitive integer type to check if the user entered an "integer", for which the mathematical defiiton is any whole number (of any size), so:

Read your user input as a String and use [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) to do the work for you:

To check if the input is an "integer" (in the mathematical sense):

```
if (input.matches("-?\\d+")) {
    // it's an integer, either negative or positive
}
```

To check it the number is "even":

```
if (input.matches(".*[02468]")) {
    // it is even
}
```

Note that [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) must match the *whole* string to return `true`, so no need for start or end anchors `^` and `$` - they are implied.

Comment: That ignores locale settings aka grouped input: German 1.000 or in English 1,000 which is both 1000. For really long integers, there is BigInteger to solve that problem.

Comment: @renes "1,000" is not an integer. It's a rendering of an integer. If I were implementing it, I would disallow non-numeric characters altogether. Otherwise you then have to deal with bad input such as "1,00,00" and *know* the preferred locale of the user, which is not necessarily known, eg is "1.000" 1000 or 1? Depends who you ask.

Comment: He receives input from the command line, hence this would be normal or possible. Just thinking about the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to tell your program what the input should like. For this you can define a set
of elements which your input must have or must not have. Then you can compare user input with that set, and can determine whether the input is legit.

One  of the standard ways is using regular expressions. You can google for regular expressions in java. or may read the tutorial at
http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html